# Regular Expression: Matching a string until certain characters

Tags: java, regex, perl

I'm trying to write a regular expression that should display a string upto the part where it finds a whitespace followed by a hyphen " -". If it doesn't find this pattern, it should display the entire string. there can be other whitespaces or hyphens in the string.

The following regex works for most string values, where the desired part is caught in $1:

```
^([^ ]+[^-]+)( -).+
```

Input strings and matched in group 1 of the above regex -

- London-Paris Tokyo --> London-Paris
- London Madrid - Paris-Berlin-Rome - Tokyo --> London Madrid
- London Paris - Berlin Tokyo --> London Paris
- London Paris --> London Paris

However, the above regex does not match the following case:

- London Paris (some-text) - berlin/tokyo

I've tried a few variations of the regex, also with negative lookahead, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

**EDIT :** *Thanks everybody for helpful and explanatory suggestions, however the answer by @Vince below worked perfect for my needs. I've added a comment below*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches

```
start of the line
followed by one or  more non-whitespaces
followed by one or more non-hyphens
followed by whitespace
followed by hyphen
followed by one or more anything
```

That's not what you want. You want

```
one or more anything
followed by whitespace
followed by hyphen
followed by one or more anything
```

You can achieve this with the following regex

```
^(.+)\s-.+$
```

If you want to match the first combination of `\s-` you can use the non-greedy `+?`, i.e.

```
^(.+?)\s-.+$
```

Though this will only match, if there's a `-` in the string. If you want to match even if that's not the case, you have to make that part optional.

```
^(.+?)(\s-.+)?$
```

Now the regex will match any string and if the string contains `-` it will save the part before that in $1.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. Your last option seems applicable to my case, I'll try your regex out!

Comment: @M42 please define "Doesn't work", because I tested it and it works for me with those two strings.

Comment: @nkrgupta I'd appreciate it, if you accepted my answer, if it's the solution you're going with :)

Comment: @Vince:For `London Paris (some-text) - berlin/tokyo` it returns `London Paris (some-text)` in group 1. That isn't wanted.

Comment: @Vince - Actually, with a little modification, the last regex works for my needs. I'm actually using a tool called iReport designer, which uses Groovy, and I have the possibility to only use conditional evaluation (condition?"true":"false") in the .jrxml file. So I'm trying to use Java's replaceAll function with a regex to output the string with the modifications, if any conditions are met (if the string contains a space followed by hyphen, print only the part before the 1st such occurance of " -") . Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a non-greedy cuantifier and do a double check after it, either a space followed by an hyphen or end of line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
        m/^(.*?)(?:\s+-|$)/ && print "$1\n";
}

__DATA__
London-Paris Tokyo
London Madrid - Paris-Berlin-Rome - Tokyo
London Paris - Berlin Tokyo
London Paris
London Paris (some-text) - berlin/tokyo
```

It yields:

```
London-Paris Tokyo
London Madrid
London Paris
London Paris
London Paris (some-text)
```

Comment: Is beginning of line symbol: ^ necessary in this regexp?

Comment: @user4035: Not really, but neither does harm.

Comment: @Birei - Thanks for the answer! It works perfect as a Perl solution (which is what I was trying as a first step), but when I replicate the regex in a JasperReport .jrxml file (it uses Java compilation, and I guess is compatible with Perl regex styles), I get compilation errors. Any idea what needs to be modified there?

Comment: @nkrgupta In Java you need to double escape the `\`, change `\s` to `\\s`.

Comment: @nkrgupta: I'm not used to `java`, but does the `regex` (the string between `^` and `$`) give you a compilation error? I think that syntax  is similar so the problem will be in another place. Besides that, I think in `java` backslashes must be escaped. Sorry that I can't be more helpful with that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like this (Java code):

```
String str = "London Paris";
String substr[] = str.split("\\s+-");
return substr[0];
```

It works for the case uses:

```
London-Paris Tokyo --> London-Paris
London Madrid - Paris-Berlin-Rome - Tokyo --> London Madrid
London Paris - Berlin Tokyo --> London Paris
London Paris --> London Paris
```

EDIT: Using ReplaceAll:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s*-.*", "")
```

Comment: I'm actually using a tool called iReport designer, which uses Groovy, and I have the possibility to only use conditional evaluation (condition?"true":"false") in the .jrxml file. So I'm trying to use Java's replaceAll function with a regex to output the string with the modifications, if any conditions are met (if the string contains a space followed by hyphen, print only the part before the 1st such occurance of " -")

Comment: Not sure if I get the replaceAll part but I have also added a code for doing the task using replaceAll.

Comment: Thanks @Averroes. your solution with replaceAll works for most cases, except the ones where there is a hyphen not following a space. There is cuts off before the hyphen anyways, which should not happen. The solution by Vince above, works for me for now. But I'd be curious to learn if you could modify your replaceAll solution to cover all cases!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your problem backwards. You are trying to find the text before your space/hyphen and extract it when what you need to do is find the text after the space/hyphen and replace it with nothing. That way an action only takes place if the regex matches otherwise you keep you original text.
I am not a Perl programmer but I think you want something like this:

```
$string =~ s/ -.*$//;
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the answer! you are right, I'm actually trying to do what you said as well, but somehow being partially successful until now. Will try out your regex as well.